# How do I work around the C# lack of assignment operator overload

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I know that overloading the assignment operator is not possible in C#... but is it possible to block the default operator?

Situation: I am developing a complex structural editor. It will allow the combination of a multitude of class objects and linking those together.

In order to be able to save these links and references between instances of many classes I need each instance to have a unique ID across all the classes. I have created an ID class (including a reference to the container object) to handle that. To make sure ID's are unique I made the class register all instances of itself in static `list<idClass> IDRegister` and all references to any ID-instance in static `list<idClass> IDReferenceList`.

Problem: upon primary assignment / creation of a new ID-instance to use, I register the ID in `IDRegister`, effectively creating two references to the object. During the use of any class instance it is now way too easy to overwrite the ID-field with another one (pre-existing or new). A normal overwrite in unregistered objects would leave an instance unreferenced and garbage collection would take care of the memory cleanup. In this case the reference to the instance in `IDRegister` (and possibly multiple times in `IDReferenceList`) would keep the ID-instance alive and with it references to possibly outdated container objects preventing cleanup of those as well. All these will leave me with a huge memory leak in my library.

Solution?

I can not accept possible memory leaks in my library. I have two options: go to C++ or find a way to prevent default assignment overwriting an existing reference to an ID-instance.

or is there a third option?

Answer (score 3):

You can make your field read only (except for the initial assignment when the object is constructed).

There are two slightly different ways to do this. The first and most reliable way is to use a `readonly` field with a public getter and no setter. Then the `id` can only be set in the constructor.

```
private readonly int id;

public int Id
{
    get
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

The second is to use a property where the setter is made private:

```
public int Id { get; private set; }
```

This allows the `id` to be changed after construction, so it's not quite the same as `readonly`. But since the setter is private it still prevents clients of your code from accidentally changing the value.

Comment: These could be also done as an `Interface` allowing your IDRegister access to the fields if it needs to change them, but only allow other programmers access to the interfaces that don't allow write access.

Comment: thank you for this, but I already thought of this. My problem is not the assignment of values within the class instance (I agree with your option there and already have that in place). My problem is the assignment of the field in the container class:

IDClass IDField = new IDClass();    followed later by IDField = new IDClass() or IDField = SomeClassInstance.IDField leaving the original ID instance stranded

Comment: @Leo: Why can't you also make that readonly? Perhaps you can come with a more complete example showing the problem?

Comment: Rats, I should have typed faster. :-)  This is the canonical answer to readonly-ness problems.

Comment: My library is supposed to allow expanding the editor with classes / objects / constructs users create. I need to force them to use the IDfiels but do not want them to have to know and remember the nitty gritty of the creation and destruction requirements all the time.

Allowing them no direct assignment will effectively remind them to use the static functions provided for assignment and destruction.

Comment: @Leo: What do you mean by stranded? If there are no more references to it, then it will be eligible for garbage collection. If you have a reference in a global container but you want it to be eligible garbage collection when there are no more *other* references then use a [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx) in your global container.

Comment: Wow... thank you so much. Never found the WeakReference class before. This will most likely solve my problem.... and some others I have not thought of yet.

Comment: Sorry I gave the wrong link before: [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx)

Comment: ok... tried it and the WeakReference seems to have some severe limitations. For one: it does not solve my problem of not being able to cascade before the assignment. Second: it might be a problem with the debug environment, but as far as I can see GC does NOT pick up the orphaned ID instances that have only WeakReferences. The WeakReference.IsAlive remains true even after forcing GC to run. I also noted that MS advises not to use WeakReference as the solution to a memory management problem. It does not offer any alternative though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can make the ID field a read-only property that is set only through your initial assignment.

Second, if your application can have memory leaks, then you're not doing cleanup properly. If you're not allocating on the GC heap, then you need to have a destructor (and generally a dispose() as well) that will ensure cleanup. This should be done somewhere that it is impossible to circumvent. I.e. if you're worried about a memory leak being caused by overwriting an ID field somewhere, then your destructor is in the wrong class.

Comment: please be assured I have destructor and dispose() all done. It is the registration itself that keeps the object alive, so overwriting the IDField in the container does not destroy the last reference to the object and therefore the destructor is not called. The dispose() assumes the user realises it has the destroy the original IDField first (as long as there are no previous references in the IDReferenceList) and then assign the new ID instance if the previous step succeeded. I already have static functions available to cover that process.

Comment: Dispose should not release the object. Instead, your finalizer should release it, while dispose should call your finalizer and then tell the GC that it doesn't need to be finalized anymore. (The finalizer is always called by the GC if not told otherwise) This gives you a "safety net" such that if your object falls off the map and gets eventually cleaned up by the GC, your unmanaged objects still get cleaned up.

Comment: As stated before: the ID instance does not fall off the map according to GC because of the registration Lists. The lists and knowledge of the lists are library internal. So, for all intents and purposes, the ID instances do fall off the map for the user that should not require knowledge of the inner workings of the class. Having to make any explicit calls prior to reassigning is begging for mistakes to be made. With the user not being able to see the lists, tracking any problem in the use of the library will be difficult at best. WeakReference class just solved my problem.